# Rails Sunspot - not working search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot

I added a sunspot gem into my rails app and my model looks like this:

```
class Lab < ApplicationRecord
    searchable do
        text :name
    end
end
```

I run the commands as the docs said (with reindex command included).

After doing:

```
@search = Lab.search do 
    fulltext "laboratory"
end
@results = search.results
```

the @results is an empty array, and I do have a record with name containing "laboratory".

I do not see any error, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `Sunspot.commit` ?

Answer (score 0):

sunspot_rails will create a callback on `save` to commit your changes to Solr, but if you're dealing with data inserted before sunspot's implementation you'll have to reindex and commit.

It's been some time since I used sunspot, but if I'm not mistaken, `reindex` won't commit changes to Solr right away, but `reindex!` will. A `Sunspot.commit` after `reindex` should also work.

The rake tasks should also help you with that:
`bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex`

https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects